# Why is prefix of underscore on public properties in my JSON result set

Tags: wcf, json, serializable

I use ASP.NET WCF to return .NET objects in JSON format through jquery calls.
When I changed my .NET classes to serializable, which I expose through methods in my WCF class, the objects property names suddenly changed from:

Name to _Name.

So all code in my javascript classes where I access json objects is wrong.

Why do the properties have a underscore prefix now?
And how do I change it back without removing the serializable attribute on the classes?

Thanks.
Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say that you "changed the class to serializable", does it mean you added the `[Serializable]` attribute on them? If this is the case: classes marked with that attribute have all of their **fields** serialized (no properties). In the example below, this class doesn't have any attributes, and it does have a parameter-less constructor, so it's considered a "POCO" (plain-old CLR object) type. POCO types have their public members (fields or properties) serialized. If you decorate it with [Serializable], then it will fall into the serializable rule.

Why do you need to mark your type with [Serializable]? If you really need to do that (for some legacy serializer), you can also decorate your type with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, which are honored by the WCF serializer. You'd add [DataContract] on the type, and [DataMember] on the *properties* which you want serialized.

```
public class Person
{
    private string _Name;
    private int _Age;

    public string Name {
        get { return this._Name; }
        set { this._Name = value; }
    }

    public string Age {
        get { return this._Age; }
        set { this._Age = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. Yes, I added the serializable attribute to the class. The reason for this is that it is required of the session state server I'm using in Windows Azure. I will try to use the datacontract and datamember as you proposed.

Comment: I tried to use datacontract and datamember but I still got an exception: SerializationException, Type XXXX in Assembly YYYY is not marked as serializable. After a call to BinaryFormatter.Deserialize.

Comment: If you need to add the [Serializable] attribute for usage with the session server, then you can add the [DataContract] attribute *in addition to* the [Serializable] one.