# Serialization of Version type different per project?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a `Version` field that is a part of a data contract, like so:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public Version version { get; set; }
```

In a REST request, that ends up getting serialized as

```
"version": {
    "_Build": 0,
    "_Major": 1,
    "_Minor": 0,
    "_Revision": 0
}
```

which is fine by me. However, I start a new project, add the project as a reference, and then when I try to send a REST request from the new project, it gets serialized as

```
"version":{
    "Major":1,
    "Minor":0,
    "Build":0,
    "Revision":-1,
    "MajorRevision":-1,
    "MinorRevision":-1
}
```

which, of course, garners me a BAD_REQUEST. Note: I am worried here about the different field names, not the actual numbers. I'm using the same `Version` type in both.

Answer (score 0):

The negative one (-1) in your revision values does mean that, the revision number is undefined.

Look for (-1) in below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.revision(v=vs.110).aspx

And the attribute `EmitDefaultValue=false` will work (whether to serialize the default value) only for default values.

Here in your case, "-1" is not a default value for integer types (Revision data type). It is zero.

May be to handle this case, use `OnSerializing()` attribute and customize the datamembers.

Roughly,

Function lifted from (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx )

```
[OnSerializing()]
internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
   if (this.version.Revision == -1)
   {
      //handle it properly 

      or

      this.version.Revision = default(int)// will not be serialized as you are using "EmitDefaultValue=false"
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not worried about the numbers, but the field names. My question was about the same Type being serialized two different ways in two different projects even when sourced from the same place.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418942/why-is-prefix-of-underscore-on-public-properties-in-my-json-result-set